# Same layout XMLs rendering differently on device

Tags: android, android-xml

I'm a bit new to Android, so please bear with me. I have two layout XML files which are practically the same. However, on my test device, they look totally different. They are files for List elements, and I know they should look the same because I copied the first one to make the second one. Here's the first one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/arrival_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/red_circle"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/arrival_dest"
    android:text = "Red Line"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/arrival_time"
    android:text = "Red Line"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/_id"
    android:text = "Red Line"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the second one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/line_icon"
    android:background="@drawable/red_circle"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/line_name"
    android:text = "Red Line"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure where else there could be an issue. If there's another XML or Java file that I need to post to determine the cause, please tell me, I'm lost. Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit 1:

Here are the screenshots for the first and second layouts, respectively:

[image: First layout]

[image: Second layout]

Not much of a difference; the second layout had a strange margin on the left and right, as well as padding in the list element.

Comment: How exactly are those xml files "practically the same" when you use different view types and a different number of views between them?

Comment: Screenshots might help clarify what the problem is too.

Comment: Luksprog, I thought the same thing, but then I copied the first layout's code into the second one's file, and the layouts still look different. At that point, the layouts were literally the same.

Comment: Eric, sorry, I just saw this. Give me a while and I'll post screenshots.

Comment: @EricFarraro I added the screenshots.

Comment: The lines aren't reaching towards the edges of the screen in the second layout so it looks like the second ListView is applying padding that the first ListView isn't applying.  Or the second ListView has margins.  Or the parent of the second ListView is applying padding.

Comment: Did you try using the WYSIWYG view?Could it be the list view or the parent view in each case have a different padding?

Comment: Thanks for including the screenshots; it's not totally clear why, but my gut says that there might be some difference between the default padding on a `View` vs the `ImageView` -- have you tried making that element consistent between the views and seeing how it looks?

Comment: @DeeV you were right! The second's ListView's fragment had padding that the first's didn't. Such a stupid mistake, but easy to overlook out of context. Thanks again for all your help!